# Import Google App Script price from Coinmarketcap Api

Tags: function, api, google-apps-script, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I have a trouble. I want to read crypto prices data.
I make to this function.

```
function getCryptoPrice(ticker) {
var ticker = ticker || "ETH";
ticker = encodeURI(ticker);
var url=("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol="+ticker);
var requestOptions = {
method: 'GET',
uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/.../cry.../listings/latest',
qs: {
start: 1,
limit: 5000,
convert: 'USD'
},
headers: {
'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'api'
},
json: true,
gzip: true
};
var httpRequest= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
var getContext= httpRequest.getContentText();
var parseData=JSON.parse(getContext);
return parseFloat(parseData.data.quote.USD.price)
}
```

When i debug the function result in picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UhZ0.png)

when result is google sheet is second picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8KuI.png)
Please, help me.
i donť now where have mistake.

I expect function without mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be?

```
parseData.data.ETH.quote.USD.price
```

Or

```
parseData.data[ticker].quote.USD.price
```